# GCE Autoscale Instance Groups Error

Tags: google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I am trying to setup an autoscaler with the "Compute Engine default service account" and receiving an error when it tries to create VMs.

```
Instance 'instance-group-1-7wsz' creation failed: Required      'compute.disks.create' permission for 'projects/[redacted]' (when acting as '[redacted]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com')

Instance 'instance-group-1-hw12' creation failed: Required 'compute.instances.setTags' permission for 'projects/[redacted]/zones/us-east1-b/instances/instance-group-1-hw12' (when acting as '[redacted]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com')
```

---

GCE Error:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by just creating a new project. I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in GCE in that the IAM account it's trying to use is not configured. To work around this:

- On your Google Developer Console.
- Go to "IAM & Admin -> IAM".
- Click "Add".
- Add as member `the-ID-shown-in-the-error-message@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` and select the Roles "Project->Editor".
- Click "Add".

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think it is a bug somewhere. I tried to add the IAM user with full permissions to the project, but to no avail. I think I may have messed it up earlier, when I was trying to delete something. Luckily, it was a practice project. 

I did create a new project named "playground" which is my production, whoops :)